# TracError: Repository not found

Tags: svn, trac, synchronization

I'm getting that error when trying to execute trac-admin /path/to/trac
repository resync /path/to/svnroot/repo1

Both paths exist. I'm trying to use Trac 0.12 with several svn
repositories. I could resync the first one without problems, but the
second one causes that error. Now, I can't resync any of them. I
always get a error like this:

```
$ trac-admin /path/to/trac repository resync /path/to/svnroot/repoN

TracError: Repository '/path/to/svnroot/repoN' not found.
```

And the repository does exist. Tested.

Software used: Ubuntu 10.04, Trac 0.12, Subversion 1.6.12, Python 2.6,
Apache2 + mod_wsgi.

Things done:

- Svn repositories created and tested, working well.
- Trac initenv and deploy admin operations executed in trac
  directory.
- Apache configured adding these lines to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
  dav_svn.conf:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/dav_svn.png

My repos are /path/to/svnroot/repo1 and /path/to/svnroot/repo2.

And these lines were added to /etc/apache2/conf.d/trac.project.conf

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/apache2.png

Same passwords are used for svn and trac: /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd,
created with htpasswd.

Any clues about the TracError problem? Thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Jorge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, when you use `trac-admin /path/to/trac repository resync myrepository` you have to specify `myrepository` by it's name and not by it's path (`repoN` in your case).

Answer (score 5):

I think I solved my problem. The trick was to execute:

trac-admin /path/to/projenv repository resync '*'

With that instruction, I could resync all my repos :-).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it also list repos, which helped me since my repos had trailing '?' not seen in trac

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin), I'm guessing that at some point you were supposed to assign the repository some kind of name for that path with the

```
repository add <repos> <path>
```

command, then all of the other commands refer to that `<repos>` name instead of the `<path>`.

Comment: I added the repository from trac admin the first time, and it worked. But when I tried with the second repository (add from admin page and the resync from console) I get that error. And I'm a bit confused about the add command syntax <repos> = path to my repository?, what is <path>?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be a name (I use trac without svn so I'm not sure).  Like `repository add MyProject /some/directory/somewhere` then you have a repository that trac calls "MyProject" and every other trac command uses "MyProject" rather than "/some/directory/somewhere".

Comment: I can add the repo with this instruction, and it appears in the trac "Browse Source" section, but without code. If I try to execute trac-admin resync (I had to do it with the first repo) I get a "Error: repository not found" message. And it exists :-(